# Vagrant box error message

Tags: vagrant, box

try to download Vagrant box on my mac system and this is the message I get.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'bahmni-team/bahmni' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'bahmni-team/bahmni'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bahmni-team/bahmni
==> default: Adding box 'bahmni-team/bahmni' (v0.80) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bahmni-team/boxes/bahmni/versions/0.80/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 963850334 bytes remaining to read
```

how do I resolve this?

After Successful Installing Vagrant box, Got this error

```
default: Importing base box 'bahmni-team/bahmni'...
Progress: 10%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/Paul/.vagrant.d/boxes/bahmni-team-VAGRANTSLASH-bahmni/0.80/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960_1463772163009_23494", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "/Users/Paul/VirtualBox VMs/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960_1463772163009_23494/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/Paul/.vagrant.d/boxes/bahmni-team-VAGRANTSLASH-bahmni/0.80/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...10%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/Users/Paul/VirtualBox VMs/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960_1463772163009_23494/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in '/Users/Paul/VirtualBox VMs/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960_1463772163009_23494/packer-virtualbox-iso-1459089960-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 877 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Comment: Looks like you might be running out of disk space?  (VERR_DISK_FULL)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error "VERR_DISK_FULL" is the error you should focus at. Your disk might have been full. So, solution would be to free some space on the disk and try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is internally using `curl` and there are issues with curl.

You can try wget on the URL as it usually works better than curl

```
wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bahmni-team/boxes/bahmni/versions/0.80/providers/virtualbox.box
```

once you have the box file you still need to add to vagrant (`vagrant box add bahmni-team/bahmni  <path to box file>`)

Comment: just tried this,  the new error "An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54"

Comment: hum ... can you run with the following `vagrant box add -c --insecure bahmni-team/bahmni `